# Single consolidated response for multiple microservices

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices

We have multiple microservices which are processing the same input in parallel.
We have to get the responses from these microservices and consolidate into a single response for bulk volumes. We thought of using hazelcast for doing this but I am just trying to understand the best and the most performant way to do this. Can someone please suggest some approach or tool for the same. Just a pointer would suffice. I just am looking for the right direction and I can do the rest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are these multiple microservices the same, meaning that output may also be the same? What kind of consolidation you need? What's the size of each response? How many microservices in parallel?

Comment: As of now 2 microservices, output will not be the same, we need to do some kind of processing on the outputs from both the services and generate a single response, but we also don't want to spend too much time doing this. Size will not be too large.

Comment: If you need a simple solution, why don't you consolidate in the service that triggered the parallel processes?

Comment: because we need to do the consolidation after the micro services are finished processing. we need results from both and then merge and send a single response out.

Comment: I still didn't understand why can't you synchronously wait for responses, consolidate, and then return (since it's a simple computing task). Do you have a third microservice triggering this parallel processing? What triggers it?

Comment: Yes there is a third microservice triggering this and I cant wait synchronously as there are bulk volumes and i really cant hold resources in case other service is down or fails to publish response

Comment: It doesn't need to be synchronous. I'll post an answer today with a few alternatives, now that the problem is clear.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a messaging queue (e.g. [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org) or [SQS](https://aws.amazon.com)) for asynchronous communication between microservices, mainly because it's probably the best way to scale and keep microservices decoupled.

In your example, you could have 3 topics (X, Y and Z) in your messaging queue. Your microservice "A" posts a message w/ inputs in topics X and Y. Microservices "B" and "C" consumes messages from X and Y, do what they need to do and post back messages in topic Z. Microservice "A" is also a consumer and reads messages/outputs from topic Z, doing the proper consolidation.

Note that, outputs from "B" and "C" could be embedded in the message, or the message could contain metadata that points to the data/output located somewhere else (e.g. database).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Spring-WebFlux is an option for your service. It allows for dispatching the request to the different services in parallel, process results and give the response to the client.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html